# Windows has no access to view my person file share from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, samba

I'm new kinda new with Linux, I have used other versions of Linux on VMs but this is my first time using it with a dedicated computer, and also using this type of Linux.

I have setup a file share with Samba on over my LAN network and I got the file share to show up in my Network on my Windows computer, but every time I try to connect to it, it shows "Windows cannot access \UBUNTUMACHINE\Test Share"

[image: Windows cannot access \UBUNTUMACHINE\Test Share]

if anyone can help me with this I would really appreciate the help. And also I do have win support on in the Samba conf and it's not commented.

Comment: You may need to log in with your Ubuntu credentials.

Comment: I made guest access available in the personal file sharing preferences

Comment: Show us how exactly you have shared this folder. Because I've made exactly the same things and all working properly ;)